# Portlet: preferences vs input

Tags: java, input, portlet, portal

From what I understood about java portlets,
the `processAction` method is generally invoked through a form in the `EDIT`   mode and ,after completing its job, can only dispatch
to another MODE, generally `VIEW` mode.

My question is: Should we use `VIEW` mode to show forms to set user preferences and also to to provide input to the portlet ?

I mean suppose we have a Weather portlet:

- A user preference is the unity of measure of temperature (C or F),
- we also have another input wich is the zip code the user can input to
  know the temparature of a location.

Should I provide both these input fields in EDIT mode ?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this. But there's nothing that forces you to do so. The specification suggests that the EDIT mode is for configuring the portlet, but it doesn't mandate this mode. You could also keep this preference with the user account (e.g. locale - en_US might imply F, or just through explicit C vs F user preference), thus totally separate from the portlet.

It's all your choice, there's no right or wrong.